# Does member of function work with collection of records in oracle?

Tags: collections, plsql, oracle11g

I have a index by table of records. Can I use member of function to check if a particular records exist in by PLSQL table or not.

```
DECLARE
  TYPE emp_name_rec is RECORD(
   firstname varchar2(10),
   lastname  varchar2(10),
   hiredate  varchar2(10));
  TYPE staff IS TABLE OF emp_name_rec;
  members staff := staff();
  rec     emp_name_rec;
  rec1    emp_name_rec;
BEGIN
  rec.firstname  := 'peter';
  rec.lastname   := 'dunn';
  rec.hiredate   := 'x';
  rec1.firstname := 'mary';
  rec1.lastname  := 'dunn';
  rec1.hiredate  := 'y';
  members.extend;
  members(members.last) := rec;
  members.extend;
  members(members.last) := rec1;
  if rec member of members then
    dbms_output.put_line('Yes its there');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('no its not');
 end if;
END;
```

This doesn't work for me, and I get no error, except I get disconnected... It looks like it compiles but it crashes my session.

Comment: Did you try it? If so what happened?

Comment: It did not work for me, but I thought there might be some other syntax or way to do this. Is it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get disconnected when I try your code in `Oracle 11g`. => **It doesn't work! as is**

From http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm ,

> You can check whether a collection is null. Comparisons such as greater than, less than, and so on are not allowed. This restriction **also applies to implicit comparisons**. [...]

Solution is: write your code:

> [..] you must **define your own notion** of what it means for collections to be greater than, less than, and so on, and write one or more functions to examine the collections and their elements and return a true or false value.

Thus you can't use `MEMBER OF` directly, but define your own `cmp_rec` function (which is quite obvious there, but not for Oracle it seems):

```
DECLARE
  TYPE emp_name_rec is RECORD(
   firstname varchar2(10),
   lastname  varchar2(10),
   hiredate  varchar2(10));
  TYPE staff IS TABLE OF emp_name_rec;
  members staff := staff();
  rec     emp_name_rec;
  rec1    emp_name_rec;
  rec_is_found boolean :=false;
  function cmp_rec ( a emp_name_rec, b emp_name_rec) 
      return boolean is
  begin
      return a.firstname=b.firstname and  a.firstname=b.firstname and a.hiredate=b.hiredate;
  end cmp_rec;

BEGIN
  rec.firstname  := 'peter';
  rec.lastname   := 'dunn';
  rec.hiredate   := 'x';
  rec1.firstname := 'mary';
  rec1.lastname  := 'dunn';
  rec1.hiredate  := 'y';
  members.extend;
  members(members.last) := rec;
  members.extend;
  members(members.last) := rec1;
  -- we must loop over the collection ourselves 
  -- - I choosed to look it all, but we could break the loop when found
  for i in 1..members.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line(members(i).firstname);
    if cmp_rec(members(i), rec) then
      rec_is_found:=true;
 end if;
  end loop;
--  if rec member of members then
-- becomes
  if rec_is_found then
    dbms_output.put_line('Yes its there');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('no its not');
 end if;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you. I had already tried with loop logic and that was obviously working for me. I just wanted to confirm about member of function. Thank you very much again.